# How to access kurento media server running inside docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, kurento

I need to configure kurento media server inside the docker container.

I can be able to configure kurento media server in my Ubuntu machine and can be able to execute the tutorial as needed.

**Links followed:**

*Kurento Media server installation:*

http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation_guide.html

*Kurento one to one call tutorial:*

http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/node/tutorial-one2one.html

Now I need to setup the same inside the docker container.

I have created a customized Docker image (Reference link: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockerimages/)

Using the procedure followed before, I have created the dockerfile

**Dockerfile content:**

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER USER1 "USER1@infinte.com"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN apt-get install git -y
RUN apt-get install curl -y
RUN echo "deb http://ubuntu.kurento.org trusty kms6" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kurento.list
RUN wget -O - http://ubuntu.kurento.org/kurento.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install kurento-media-server-6.0 -y
RUN sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 start
RUN sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 stop
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
RUN sudo apt-get install -y nodejs -y
RUN sudo npm install -g bower -y
RUN git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node.git
RUN cd kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call && pwd
RUN cd kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call && git checkout 6.5.0
RUN sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 start
RUN cd kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call && npm install
EXPOSE 8080
```

I can be able to build the docker image and execute the kurento tutorial inside the container.

**Here is the proof:**

```
root@6be9dd5da412:/kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call# npm start

> kurento-one2one-call@6.5.0 start /kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call
> node server.js

Kurento Tutorial started
Open https://localhost:8443/ with a WebRTC capable browser
```

But still now I am unable to access the same using the link.

I guess I am missing something regarding the port forwarding or anything.

Some one help me with the same.

Answer (score 2):

I can be able to find the solution.

Issue is with the port exposed.

Service is started in port 8443 ,But I am trying to expose port 8080.

So Changed the same as EXPOSE 8443.

Then in is working fine.

Command to run the container:

```
docker run -t -i -p 8443:8443 ouruser/webrtc /bin/bash
```